# Clickable area on a path

Tags: canvas, imagemap

What methods is to make the area click on the figure?

Image-map does not fit, because should consider resizing images.

For exemple, i have html construction:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="image.png" alt="image"/>
</a>
```

css:

```
a { width: 30%; }
img{ width: 100%; }
```

[Image, with area clique](http://s2.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2012/11/777c784582ee7c4ab396e3dade4063e9.jpg)